# webpack: Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined

Tags: webpack, electron, external

I've been creating an Electron project using

```
yarn create electron-app my-new-app --template=webpack
```

My `webpack.main.config.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: './src/main.js',
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules: require('./webpack.rules'),
  },
  externals: {
    'fs': 'commonjs fs'
  }

};
```

my `renderer.js` contains the line:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: fs is not defined
    at Object.fs (index.js:473)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:502)
    at fn (index.js:713)
    at eval (renderer.js?5bd3:55)
    at Module../src/renderer.js (index.js:352)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:502)
    at index.js:1559
    at index.js:1561
```

The buggy code is this:

```
/***/ "fs":
/*!*********************!*\
  !*** external "fs" ***!
  \*********************/
/***/ ((module) => {

"use strict";
module.exports = fs;

/***/ })
```

(fs is not defined at all)

Comment: Check you've got `nodeIntegration` set to `true` and `contextIsolation` set to `false` on your `BrowserWindow`.

Comment: There are two webpack config files. It seems you need to add the externals configuration on both files.

Comment: If you set target: 'electron-main' and target: 'electron-renderer' on your webpack config files you don't have to manually add externals such as fs, webpack takes care of it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it that way:

I've been adding the external config to `webpack.renderer.config.js`, too. Then it works.